# Iterate through table and create an array in js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html-table, tablerow

I want to iterate through my dynamically created table and create an array of elements Project Name, Client Name, and Field Rate at each index to populate and pass through a JSON object

Here is how my table looks:

```
        <table id="project-table" class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Project Name</th>
            <th>Client Name</th>
            <th>Field Rate</th>
            <th>Delete Row</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <%--jquery will append our data here...     --%>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" onclick="projectTable()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Row</button>

function projectTable() {

projectRows = projectRows + 1;

var $tbody = $('#project-table').find('tbody');
var $id = $("");
var $tr = $("<tr>");

$id.append(
    "<hidden id='projectId'/>" +
    "<hidden id='projectVersion'/>"
);

$tr.append(
    "<td>" + "<input class='form-control' id='inputProjectName' placeholder='Project Name' type='text'>" + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + "<input class='form-control' id='inputClientName' placeholder='Client Name' type='text'>" + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + "<input class='form-control' id='inputRate' placeholder='Rate' type='text'></td>" +
    "<td>" + "<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this)'>" + "</td>");
$tbody.append($id);
$tbody.append($tr);}
```

projectTable() is called each time I click an Add new Row button.
I want to be able to depending on how many rows have been created create an array containining the info from each of the rows like so:

```
            projectList: [
            {
                id: projectId,
                version: projectVersion,
                projectName: projectName,
                clientName: clientName,
                fieldRate: fieldRate
            }
```

but with multiple objects I have tried a few different for loops but they haven't worked for me.

Comment: What have you tried? A simple loop like `$('#project-table').find('tr').each(...)` loops through all rows and you just have to extract the data you need from the `<td>` elements!?

Comment: the problem I have ran into has been figuring out how to extract the data from only the first three as I do not want the Delete Button to be part of the extraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it by selecting all the `tr` and then for each of those select the `input` elements to build your data.

Some issues in your current code:

- You cannot have static `id` property values in your rows, as `id` values must be unique
- The custom `hidden` element cannot be child of `tbody`. I don't see how you would need this element.

I have altered some other things in your code to make it more jQuery-like:

```js
function projectTable() {
    $('#project-table>tbody').append(
        $("<tr>").append(
            $("<td>").append($("<input>").addClass("form-control")
                .attr({placeholder: "Project Name", type: "text"})),
            $("<td>").append($("<input>").addClass("form-control")
                .attr({placeholder: "Client Name", type: "text"})),
            $("<td>").append($("<input>").addClass("form-control")
                .attr({placeholder: "Rate", type: "text"})),
            $("<td>").append($("<input>").addClass("form-control delete")
                .attr({type: "button"}).val("Delete"))
        )
    );
}

$(document).on("click", ".delete", function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});

$('#get').click(function () {
    var data = $.map($('#project-table>tbody>tr'), function (tr) {
        var $inp = $('input', tr);
        return {
            project: $inp.eq(0).val(),
            client: $inp.eq(1).val(),
            rate: $inp.eq(2).val(),
        };
    });
    $('#jsonout').text(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="project-table" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Project Name</th>
        <th>Client Name</th>
        <th>Field Rate</th>
        <th>Delete Row</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="projectTable()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Row</button>
<button type="button" id="get" class="btn btn-primary">Get JSON</button>
<pre id="jsonout"></pre>
```

Comment: I need the Id and Version for update purposes on the object. Is there a better way to handle this sort of thing?

Comment: Yes, you can put [`data-`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) attributes on the `tr` element.

Comment: I ended up going a different route, but did find this to be a helpful point in starting. thank you for the assistance.